# \multirow inside table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[color=red,opacity=0.1,contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listingsutf8]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pifont}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\author{Marko Frelih\\Firm\\\texttt{email}}
\title{Install manual}
\date{Ljubljana, Marec 2015}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline Paket & Opis\\
            \hline jre7-openjdk-headless & Java zagonsko okolje brez grafi\v{c}nih orodij\\
            \hline jre7-openjdk & Poplno Java zagonsko okolje\\
            \hline jdk7-openjdk & Java razvojno okolje\\
            \hline openjdk7-doc & Dokumentacija Java razvojena okolja\\
            \hline openjdk7-src & Izvorna koda Java razvojnega okolja\\
            \hline jre8-openjdk-headless & Java zagonsko okolje brez grafi\v{c}nih orodij\\
            \hline jre8-openjdk & Poplno Java zagonsko okolje\\
            \hline jdk8-openjdk & Java razvojno okolje\\
            \hline openjdk8-doc & Dokumentacija Java razvojena okolja\\
            \hline openjdk8-src & Izvorna koda Java razvojnega okolja\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{\textit{Archlinux Java} paketi}\label{tblArchlinuxJavaPackages}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which results in table, visible in following screenshot:

[image: Java packages]

This is all ok, but I would like to add vertical `multicolumn`/`multirow` before column 1 that will describe `Java version 7` and `Java version 8` packages, as seen in following screenshot:
[image: Java packages with versions]

and inside upper blank rectangle (cell) with vertical text `verzija 7` and inside lower blank rectangle (cell) with vertical text `verzija 8`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `multirow` and `\rotatebox` to get what you want. I have not cleaned up your code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[color=red,opacity=0.1,contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listingsutf8]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\author{Marko Frelih\\Firm\\\texttt{email}}
\title{Install manual}
\date{Ljubljana, Marec 2015}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-3} \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Paket & Opis\\
            \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{verzija 7}} &
                    jre7-openjdk-headless & Java zagonsko okolje brez grafi\v{c}nih orodij\\
            \cline{2-3} & jre7-openjdk & Poplno Java zagonsko okolje\\
            \cline{2-3} &  jdk7-openjdk & Java razvojno okolje\\
            \cline{2-3} &  openjdk7-doc & Dokumentacija Java razvojena okolja\\
            \cline{2-3} &  openjdk7-src & Izvorna koda Java razvojnega okolja\\
            \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{verzija 8}} &
                   jre8-openjdk-headless & Java zagonsko okolje brez grafi\v{c}nih orodij\\
            \cline{2-3} &  jre8-openjdk & Poplno Java zagonsko okolje\\
            \cline{2-3} &  jdk8-openjdk & Java razvojno okolje\\
            \cline{2-3} &  openjdk8-doc & Dokumentacija Java razvojena okolja\\
            \cline{2-3} &  openjdk8-src & Izvorna koda Java razvojnega okolja\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{\textit{Archlinux Java} paketi}\label{tblArchlinuxJavaPackages}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW, that is one quick solution!